# How to return multiple values from multiprocessing pool as a dataframe?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I have an array of orders of parameters `pqd` for `arima` like:

```
[(0, 0, 0),
 (0, 1, 0),
 (0, 2, 0),
 (0, 3, 0),
 (1, 0, 0),
 (1, 1, 0),
 (1, 2, 0),
 (1, 3, 0),
 (2, 0, 0),
 (2, 1, 0),
 (2, 2, 0),
 (2, 3, 0)]
```

I want  to eval arima's performance using that order of parameters using multiprocessing.
however I have two issues:

1. The eval function takes 3 parameters
2. The eval function returns 2 results

How do I return results for both error and model as a dataframe?

Here is what I have tried:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
#this computes error and return a model
def eval_model_parameters(a,b,order):
    #use order PARAMETER somehow to compute model 
    error = a*b/2
    model = a
    return [error,model]

p = [0, 1 , 2]
d = [0, 1 , 2 ,3]
q = [0]
pdq = list(itertools.product(p, d, q)) 

p = Pool(7)
func = eval_model_parameters(1, 2, pdq)
res  = p.map(func, pdq)  
p.close()
```

I tried doing this to pass parameters to function

```
func = eval_model_parameters(1, 2, pdq)
```

And this to return results

```
res  = p.map(func, pdq)
```

but I get

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> RemoteTraceback                           Traceback (most recent call last)
> RemoteTraceback: 
> """
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 121, in worker
>     result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
>   File "Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
>     return list(map(*args))
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
> """
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-53-7743fd9ca60b> in <module>
>      13 p = Pool(7)
>      14 func = eval_model_parameters(1, 2, pdq)
> ---> 15 res  = p.map(func, pdq)
>      16 p.close()
>      17 
>
> Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
>     266         in a list that is returned.
>     267         '''
> --> 268         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
>     269 
>     270     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):
>
> Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py in get(self, timeout)
>     655             return self._value
>     656         else:
> --> 657             raise self._value
>     658 
>     659     def _set(self, i, obj):
>
> TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
> ```

What is the correct way to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the pool.map function should be a callable object. In your case, you have called the function yourself and then passing the results to pool.map function.
Try passing the function itself to the pool.map like below:

```
p.map(eval_model_parameters, pdq)
```

Now when you change the above line and run the code you will see that the tuple of pdq list is getting passed as a single argument. 
To solve that please follow this question [multiple args to pool.map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Understand it, but what about parameters a and b ?

Comment: they will be the first and second values in the tuple of pdq list.

Comment: could you please elaborate it?, still dont get the idea

Comment: The list pdq consist of tuple each having three values, when we map some function with this tuple then these three values will be passed as arguments to that function.

Comment: Ok, last question is how to return multiple values from the function that evaluates, maybe a list or something like that?

Comment: You are already returning a list of values in eval_model_parameters function, right?

Comment: so in the line res  = p.map(func, pdq)   res has a list of lists of results?

Comment: yes the variable "res" is list of lists, having two values returned from the function.